# R Extraxt time varying smoothing parameters from gam

Tags: r, var, smoothing, gam

I am trying to extract the time varying smoothing parameter of my gam.

This is the model:

```
gam1 <- gam(as.numeric(A5_1)~s(tt,k=k)+s(tt,by=A5_1L,k=k)+s(tt,by=A5_2L,k=k)+
            s(tt,by=A5_5L,k=k)+s(tt,by=A5_9L,k=k),data=data_subset)
gam2 <- gam(as.numeric(A5_2)~s(tt,k=k)+s(tt,by=A5_1L,k=k)+s(tt,by=A5_2L,k=k)+
            s(tt,by=A5_5L,k=k)+s(tt,by=A5_9L,k=k),data=data_subset)
gam5 <- gam(as.numeric(A5_5)~s(tt,k=k)+s(tt,by=A5_1L,k=k)+s(tt,by=A5_2L,k=k)+
            s(tt,by=A5_5L,k=k)+s(tt,by=A5_9L,k=k),data=data_subset)
gam9 <- gam(as.numeric(A5_9)~s(tt,k=k)+s(tt,by=A5_1L,k=k)+s(tt,by=A5_2L,k=k)+
            s(tt,by=A5_5L,k=k)+s(tt,by=A5_9L,k=k),data=data_subset)
```

`summary(gam1)` look like this:

[image]

I can create plots showing smoothing parameters over time like this:

```
plot(gam1, select=2,ylim=c(-3,1),rug=F,xlab="time points",
     ylab=substitute(paste("Joy",italic("(t-1)"), "on Joy",italic("(t)"))))
```

Plot is looking like this:

[image: plot_gam]

So far I found the `predict.gam()` function:

`predict.gam(gam1, type = "terms")`

The predict function gives me:

[image: predict_gam]

(nrows=103)

However the output doesn't match the plot.
The line in the plot start around 0.2, whereas the smoothing
Parameter in from `predict.gam()` is around 1.1. How can I extract
the correct smoothing parameters over time?

In genereal I want these parameters, so that i can create different
qgraphs() over time. One qgraph at the beginning, middle and end.
Like network analysis plots. If there is a direct way of
creating multiple qgraph() plots from time varying gam, I will
gladly take this as well.

Maybe I will even use qgraph.animate() once I created a matrix
of those Parameters.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't look like the plot because the plot is showing the estimated effect for a 100 ordered values over the observed range of `tt`. The `predict()` call is giving you back the fitted values for your data because you didn't supply anything to the `newdata` argument.

Two options are to:

1. Save the output from `plot.gam()`: `plt <- plot.gam(....)`

   Now `plt` will contain an object with all the data used to create the plot. If you plot all smooths rather than just one, you'll get a list back with a data object per smooth.
2. Prepare some new data to predict at and pass that to `predict()` as `newdata`. You'll need to provide data for `tt` plus all the `by` variables used in the model. `expand.grid()` is useful for this.

Comment: Thanks alot! I have chosen the first option.
I found this table earlier as well. Hoewever i was confused
by the number of timepoints (=100), that why i disgarded it.

My data have 107 time points and the gam1 uses 87 date
(excluding NAs). Are 100 timepoints due to some
degrees of freedoms calculations, that I dont understand yet?

Thank again, I wish you a nice christmas! :)

Comment: Look at the args to `plot.gam()`; it has `n=100` which is used for univariate smooths. (I said 200 in my answer and will adjust that now). This is just an arbitrary default that gets relatively nice representations of smooth functions that are not too wiggly. If you have much more complex smooths you need to increase `n` when plotting to get a nicer plot. But this is what dictates how many values are in the object returned by `plot.gam()`